# Unsigned 32-bit integer to binary string function

Tags: c

I've been trying to solidify my understanding of the binary number system by writing code. So, I tried to write a function with what I currently understand about the binary system that returns a string representation of the binary number representing the input.

Any feedback regarding how I may optimize the program is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

```
char *uint32_to_binarystr(uint32_t n) {
    if (n != UINT32_MAX) {
        int expb2 = 0;              // Exponent of 2.      
        static char binarystr[33];  // 32 bits + 1 termination NULL char.
        binarystr[32] = '\0';       // Add terminating NULL char.
        memset(binarystr, '0', 32); // Initialize 32-bit string as 0.
        while (n != 0) {                         // Continue until n has been completely represented by a sum of powers of 2.
            while (1 << expb2 <= n) { expb2++; } // Find the power of 2 that yields a result greater than n. 
            expb2 -= 1;                          // Once this number is found, we are sure that the previous power yields the largest power of 2 less than n.
            n -= 1 << expb2;                     // We've found a power of 2 to represent this "chunk" of n. Reduce n by the same amount.
            binarystr[31 - expb2] = '1';         // Set the bit at the index with expb2 digits following it to 1.
            expb2 = 0;                           // Reset exponent of 2 and repeat.
        }
        return binarystr;
    } else {
        /*
        In the case that UINT32_MAX is to be represented, just return hard-coded string. 
        Why? 
        A 32-bit shift is not doable in some cases:
        https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7401888/why-doesnt-left-bit-shift-for-32-bit-integers-work-as-expected-when-used
        */
        static char binarystr[33];  
        binarystr[32] = '\0';       
        memset(binarystr, '1', 32); 
        return binarystr;
    }
}
```

Comment: *solidify my understanding of the binary number system*:  I pedagogically suggest attempting a general algorithm to convert any given (input) number with its base, to any given (input) base. Binary, Hex, Decimal, it is all the same really. But not Roman numerals of course!  Your code seems to be a bit shifting exercise and necessarily machine (CPU) specific.

Comment: @radarbob 32 bit integers stored on digital (aka binary) computers are not machine specific! Bit shifting is always equivalent to multiplying by a power of two (left shifting) or dividing by a power of two (losing the remainder) (right shifting). The only (unlikely) possible machine specific representation is for negative numbers. AFAIK all modern CPUs use [two's complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signed_number_representations#Two's_complement) to represent negative binary numbers since addition, subtraction, and left and right bit shifting all work the same as for positive numbers.

Comment: @radarbob: It's not all the same: bases that are powers of 2 let you get the most-significant digit first, because each digit represents a group of bits in the binary number.  This is what makes it possible to efficiently convert to hex in parallel with SIMD, for example.  ([How to convert a binary integer number to a hex string?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53823756)).  But for bases that aren't powers of 2, you need actual division, and the low digit depends on *all* the higher bits.  So you have to start with `x % base` ; `x /= base;` and store the digits in reverse.

Comment: @ReversedEngineer: Yes, and ISO C guarantees that integral types are binary.  This code isn't using signed integer (except by mistake with `1 << expb2` which should be `1UL << expb2`) so it doesn't even depend on two's complement.  But yes, I don't know of any modern CPUs that use anything else either; IIRC C++20 is going to drop one's complement and sign/magnitude, leaving only two's complement for integral types (and hopefully guaranteeing that `>>` on signed types is an arithmetic right shift, not implementation-defined.  unsigned `>>` shifts in zeros, instead of copies of the sign bit).

Comment: Your program is missing test cases, like  `test(strcmp(uint32_to_binarystr(0), "0000..0000") == 0)`, where `test` is an `assert`-like function or macro for testing. Write a bunch of correct tests and then massage the code until they all pass.

Comment: *...  are not machine specific!*  Well, I suppose the abstraction layer that is the C language enables this code to run on a given C implementation.  I wouldn't bet a $100B manned mission to Mars on it though. For example I recall an Arian rocket that performed an unscheduled disassembly due to an overflow bug.  Don't get me wrong, this bit shifting program does have educational value. Here is my epitaph when I go to that big parking orbit in the sky:  "How the hell did this happen?"

Comment: Related: [Bytes to binary conversion function](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/260111) is a similar codereview, but starting from a more "normal" unsigned integer -> ASCII base-2 digits function.

Comment: @radarbob, it's worth scanning the [Wikipedia page on binary numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_number) (for pedagogical reasons), and noting that the words "CPU", "processor", "compile", and "compiler" do not appear on the page. The binary representation of integers has as little to do with computers, compliers, or the C language, as the ordinary decimal representation we all learned before we were six years old.

Comment: It's also worth noting that all modern digital computers ("machines")  are binary (i.e. there are only two digits in the "digital" part). Since "ISO C guarantees that integral types are binary" (thanks, @PeterCordes), nothing about any of this is "machine" specific.

Comment: @radarbob: The implementation in the question has some bugs, some of which may be machine-dependent.  The answers to this code-review point this out.   A cleanly-written C function to format a `uint32_t` into a 32-byte `char []` array of ASCII `'0'` and `'1'` bytes won't.  Not even if you compile it on a hypothetical C implementation that has to emulate binary numbers on top of a ternary machine, e.g. implementing `n & 1` as remainder by 2, because ISO C guarantees that `n % 2` and `n & 1` are the same thing for `unsigned` integral types.

Comment: If you're trying to learn about binary in general, it makes sense to *not* just treat it as any other base.

Comment: @radarbob I realised maybe you felt it was the "bit shifting exercise" that's "machine (CPU) specific"? If so, please consider: shifting an ordinary decimal number N places to the left (adding zeroes on the right) is the same as multiplying it by 10^N. Right-shifting the number N places (losing N right-most digits) is the same as dividing it by 10^N (and losing the reminder). Only pen and paper so far! Similarly, shifting a binary number N places to the left (on paper or with the `<< N` operator in C) multiplies it by 2^N, and right-shifting divides it by 2^N. Nothing machine specific at all.

Comment: Bit shifting per se is not at issue. Rather, hard coding for 32 bits. If this program cannot compile on a 16 bit C implementation then it can never blow up there. Given the `uint32_t` data type, it is type-safe but what are the (potential) considerations executing on 64+ bit computers? If anything, is it desirable to take advantage of the full 64+ bit registers? That Arian rocket blew up when "Arian 4 sized numbers" overflowed when fed the volume and larger bit sized telemetry generated by Arian 5 performance improvements.

Answer (score 19):

The interface is problematic.  What output does this code produce?

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
    const char *s1 = uint32_to_binarystr(0);
    const char *s2 = uint32_to_binarystr(1000000);
    printf("%s\n%s\n", s1, s2);
}
```

You might expect it to output `00000000000000000000000000000000` followed by `00000000000011110100001001000000`, but that's not what we get.  Do you see why?

The problem is

> ```
>     static char binarystr[33];  
>     ⋮
>     return binarystr;
> ```

`s1` and `s2` both point to the same data!

The two usual solutions to this problem are

- return newly-allocated memory that the caller must `free()`, or
- have the caller supply a buffer into which to write.

I tend to prefer the latter - it avoids overhead of heap allocation in many cases, and reduces the risk of memory leaks due to misuse.

I would write that as

```
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <string.h>

bool uint32_to_binarystr(char *binarystr, size_t len, uint32_t n) {
    if (len < 33) {
        // 32 bits + 1 terminating NUL char
        return false;
    } 
    ⋮
    return true;
}
```

```
int main(void)
{
    char s1[33];
    char s2[33];
    assert(uint32_to_binarystr(s1, sizeof s1, 0));
    assert(uint32_to_binarystr(s2, sizeof s2, 1000000));
    printf("%s\n%s\n", s1, s2);
}
```

Passing the length available might seem unnecessary (who would supply a buffer that's too short?) but it does turn out to be a good idea in practice.

---

For the algorithm, I would approach  this with a "moving bit" (for simplicity, I'll demonstrate the `uint8_t` version).  If we start with our number `abcdefgh` and an initial mask `10000000`, then we can decide whether the first digit is 0 or 1 using a bitwise AND operation `n & mask`.  Then move to the next digit by shifting `mask` rightwards by one.  When the bit runs off the end, `mask` becomes zero, and we know we're done.

In code (and switching back to 32 bits), that looks like:

```
for (uint32_t mask = 0x80000000;  mask;  mask >>= 1) {
    if (n & mask) {
        /* we have a 1 bit */
    } else {
        /* we have a 0 bit */
    }
}
```

We can simplify the body of the loop, too, because C guarantees that `'1'` is one more than `'0'`:

```
char digit = '0' + ((n & mask) != 0);
```

If we write all the characters like this, then there's no need for `memset()` at the beginning.

Putting this all together, I have a replacement which is worth studying:

```
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stddef.h>
#include <stdint.h>

bool uint32_to_binarystr(char *buf, size_t len, uint32_t n) {
    if (len < 33) {
        // 32 bits + 1 terminating NUL char
        return false;
    }
    for (uint32_t mask = 0x80000000;  mask;  mask >>= 1) {
        bool bit_is_set = n & mask;
        *buf = '0' + bit_is_set;
        ++buf;
    }
    *buf = '\0';          /* add the terminator */
    return true;
}
```

Comment: `*buf++ = '0' + ((n & mask) != 0);` is really cryptic to read for beginners though. I would split that expression up in several lines, to increase readability.

Comment: @Lundin, I tried to offset that by showing the intermediate step with `if`/`else`.  But I've now edited to break up the expression.

Comment: Turns out I was writing an answer with nearly the same solution as you did that :) The bool seems to give slightly better machine code than `if(n & mask) *buf = '0'; else *buf = '1';`.

Comment: What happens if len does not match the actual size of buf, especially if buf is smaller? Never trust input!

Comment: @Glen, It's a common idiom in C to pass buffer and length as a pair (c.f. `strncpy()`, `sprintf()` etc).  Here, we're trusting the _programmer_ to supply the actual capacity, not trusting _input_.  That's a big difference!

Comment: @TobySpeight, The length in strncpy() specifies how many characters are to be copied from src to dst, not necessarily the length of either buffer. There is no length parameter in sprintf().

Comment: Typo - `snprintf`

Answer (score 9):

Your code has a possible bug, depending on your CPU/compiler.

You are treating `UINT32_MAX` (`0xFFFFFFFF`) as a special case, however, you could run into problems with any value greater that `0x80000000`.

For example, if we let `n` be `0x80000001`, then ...

```
        int expb2 = 0;
        ...
        while (n != 0) {
            while (1 << expb2 <= n) { expb2++; } 
            ...
```

we start increasing `expb2`, shifting `1` over by more and more bits until it is greater than `n`.

But on a 32-bit architecture, since `1 << 31` is less `n`, you increase `expb2` to `32`. and `1 << 32` will overflow 32-bit integer, which results in undefined behaviour, but my experience, the result will be either `0` or `1`.  Since this is less than `n`, the loop continues, and the `while (1 << expb2 <= n) { expb2++; }` loop will continue forever.

Instead of trying to bit shift to find the ideal bit to start at, since you have a known type (`uint32`) with a known bit width (`32`), simply start at bit 31 and work your way down.

```
char *uint32_to_binarystr(uint32_t n) {
    static char binarystr[33];
    binarystr[32] = '\0';
    memset(binarystr, '0', 32);

    for(int expb2 = 31; expb2 >= 0; expb2--) {
        if ((uint32_t)1 << expb2 >= n) {
            binarystr[31 - expb2] = '1';
            n -= 1 << expb2;
        } 
    }
    return binarystr;
}
```

Since the maximum shift is 31, there is no need to special case `UINT32_MAX`.

Comment: Thanks for the informative feedback and debugging! The `UINT32_MAX` special case felt really "hacky" when I implemented it, so thanks again for the alternative algorithm.

Comment: `1 << 31` is already signed-overflow UB (assuming 32-bit signed `int`; it could be a shift wider than the type width on a C implementation with 16-bit `int`.  That's why it should be `1UL << whatever`.  (@SeanXie).  And normally you'd want to test if that bit is set, like `n & mask`, not arithmetic compare.  So +1 for pointing out that special-casing some inputs is super weird, but you could say more.  Also, there were two separate `static char binarystr[33];` buffers in different branches, and the function returned a different one in the special case! Declare it outside the `if`.

Comment: @PeterCordes Good catch!  I’d use `(uint32_t)1` instead of `1UL` to avoid the possible inefficiency of a `long` being 64 bits.

Comment: @AJNeufeld: True, that could save a byte of code-size on x86-64, avoiding a REX prefix.  Unlike `ULL`, it won't be a 64-bit type on 32-bit machines; on mainstream C implementations, `long` isn't wider than a single register (for a 32-bit or wider machine).  `(uint32_t)1` is never worse, and can be slightly more efficient, and does match the type you're using it with, so yeah that's a good choice.  Using a 32-bit type lets the compiler know that the shift definitely doesn't need to be able to go past bit #31.

Answer (score 8):

As already said in other reviews, you should switch to caller allocation. And there's no initialize the string at all, just overwrite all of it.

As for the algorithm itself, or in general, go with readability and keep things simple. When we do so, we tend to get efficiency for free too. This seems like a good compromise between readability and performance:

```
void uint32_to_binstr (char dst[33], uint32_t n)
{
  for(size_t i=0; i<32; i++)
  {
    bool one = n & (1u << i);
    size_t index = 32-i-1; 
    dst[index] = '0' + one;
  }
  dst[32]='\0';
}
```

There's a rule of thumb to always keep (for) loops as simple as possible, as close to idea ideal `for(size_t i=0; i<n; i++)` as possible. When you do this, the code tends to turn both more readable and efficient. (A bit of fiddling around with disassemblers showed me that this gave somewhat better machine code than the down counting versions or the versions right shifting a mask.)

Since I counted from 0 to 31, I need to compensate for that when determining the index used for storage - the above actually fills the array from the back to the front. The calculation `32-i-1` gives 31, 30, 29...

The `bool one = n & (1u << i);` is basically the same as `if(n & (1u << i))` and will likely result in a branch too, probably there's way around it without turning the code real ugly.

Note that I used `1u` for shifting, since `1` gives a signed `int` and shifting signed numbers is a very bad idea. In case of left shift we might shift data into the sign bit = undefined behavior bug. In case of right shift we don't know if we get arithmetic or logical shift = non-portable code and generally a bad idea.

Peeking at the resulting machine code (gcc x86 -O3):

```
uint32_to_binstr:
        lea     r9, [rdi-32]
        mov     rax, rdi
        mov     r8d, 1
.L2:
        mov     ecx, edi
        mov     edx, r8d
        sub     ecx, eax
        sal     edx, cl
        and     edx, esi
        cmp     edx, 1
        mov     edx, 48
        sbb     dl, -1
        sub     rax, 1
        mov     BYTE PTR [rax+32], dl
        cmp     r9, rax
        jne     .L2
        mov     BYTE PTR [rdi+32], 0
        ret
```

This is reasonably compact and not many branches.

Now since we decided to use a trivial, readable loop, we automatically get lots of advantages we hadn't even considered from the start. Suppose we want to modify the code to drop leading zeroes or just print a certain amount of digits? We can use pretty much the very same code, just swap out the hard-coded `32` for a parameter and then change the order of parameters:

```
void uint32_to_binstr (uint32_t n, size_t digits, char dst[digits])
{
  for(size_t i=0; i<digits; i++)
  {
    bool one = n & (1u << i);
    size_t index = digits-i-1; 
    dst[index] = '0' + one;
  }
  dst[digits]='\0';
}
```

Comment: Interesting, I've always counted down for efficiency, because if you count up, you have to load the value that your counting up to into a register every time you go through the loop for the comparison, whereas if you count down, you only have to load the value into the register once and then decrement it every loop, the comparison against 0 to terminate the loop is basically free, no need to load 0 into another register. But then, the last time I cared about efficiency at this low a level, my target processor only had 2 registers and an accumulator, maybe you have more registers to work with.

Comment: Variable-count shifting isn't that great.  If you're going to start at the LSB and store backwards into the buffer, `n >>= 1;` is a lot more attractive.  Then `digit = '0' + (n & 1)`.  Best of all, `i` isn't involved in anything except the array index anymore, so that's just a decrement towards 0, as @GlenYates pointed out, letting the loop branch be `dec reg / jnz`.  Or not; to get the indexing right with a function-arg `digits`, GCC does the decrement before using it for a store, so it has to `test` after.  https://godbolt.org/z/e68oo6cEG.  But still significantly fewer instructions.

Comment: Unless I disallow `digits=0` as an input, I don't see a great way to use a canonical `for()` loop structure instead of `--i` at the top of the loop body.  Otherwise, `for (size_t i = digits - 1 ; i != 0 ; i--)` could wrap to SIZE_MAX, which would be nice to avoid.  It would make some sense to rule out digits=0 in your variable-digits version, though, to allow an asm do{}while loop structure without any check before entering the first iteration that stores the LSB at dst[digits-1].

Comment: Also, `unsigned` is allowed to be narrower than uint32_t.  `1UL << count` would be safely portable.  (But usually worse than just shifting as a loop-carried dependency; most CPUs have efficient low-latency right-shift-by-1.  Variable-count shift is only good if you're going to use it to start at the MSB, and then only because C doesn't have an easy rotate-left.)

Comment: @GlenYates Down-counting as a way of manual optimization is a very old trick from back in the days when compilers were horrible. Modern compilers should be able to that optimization for you. Various more exotic embedded systems compilers may still struggle with it, but overall I'd say it's somewhat rare to find such bad compilers still out there.

Comment: @PeterCordes There was no particular target mentioned for this example, I just picked x86 as an example. Obviously this code can be optimized much more, using look-up tables. I just picked a reasonable compromise between readability and performance.

Comment: I was going to say that the improved asm is mostly independent of ISA, but https://godbolt.org/z/d4rrr9hvr shows that GCC11 auto-vectorizes your version for ARM, but not mine.  (Even if I change mine to use `dst[i-i]` so I can use a canonical `for(size_t i=digits; i != 0 ; --i)` loop.)  But for an ARM without NEON, my version is clearly much better: https://godbolt.org/z/4eWqbvshG - GCC misses the optimization of doing `n & (1u << i)` as ` (n>>i) & 1`, and instead materializes `1 << i` with a shift, for a `tst` / `ite ne` / `movne #1` / `moveq #0` then add!  (not even mov #48 / `addne #1` :/)

Comment: Actually on 2nd look, I'm not sure GCC's auto-vectorization is actually profitable.  Looks totally bonkers, loading 32 separate `.word` constants, 2 at a time.  For fixed `digits=32` it's easier to see how crazy it is, even without any cleanup loops. https://godbolt.org/z/nxbbehxj6.  Looks vastly less efficient than a NEON equivalent of [is there an inverse instruction to the movemask instruction in intel avx2?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36488675), or [How to create a byte out of 8 bool values (and vice versa)?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51750902)

Comment: @PeterCordes Reading auto vectorized disassembly is beyond me, I can never tell if it is doing something very clever or just going nuts :) That's the point where I'd rather just benchmark by clocking it. Then you get to see the cache use aspect too.

Comment: Or for ASCII '0'/'1' specifically, [Convert 16 bits mask to 16 bytes mask](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67201469) shows an AVX2 way that should also be doable with NEON.  Oh, and that was originally from a Code Review of a binary->ASCII base 2 dump Q&A [Bytes to binary conversion function](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/260147)

Comment: Yeah, in this case it might be better than scalar for the fixed digits=32 case, although cache footprint is way larger.  It's very much worse than a *good* SIMD implementation, though. Probably it's keeping copies of the whole 32-bit number, instead of slicing it up into the byte containing the bit of interest (hence needing 32 words instead of 32 bytes of mask data?), but it's more SIMD asm than I want to read either.

Comment: Does specifying the parameter as `char dst[33]` provide any type safety?  I don't think it does, and if it did you wouldn't be able to pass a pointer you created with `malloc`.

Comment: @MarkRansom Some static analysers might be able to provide better diagnostics if you do, while at the same time it won't prevent compilation. But mostly it is self-documenting code. `char dst [32+1]` is another option.

Answer (score -5):

Computers convert decimal to binary anytime people code. As such, computers probably have a very fast way to do it. Ben Eater, on YouTube, has a video about hardwiring a decimal to hex converter with discrete logic gates. I imagine a similar principle can apply here. Where there should be some way you can use it if the computer can't.

If you have a good G.P.U. In theory using CUDA or something similar with an actual multiply instruction might be better if you were converting a lot of numbers. But at the same time I see no reason for that.

You could probably optimize by using assembly. When we write something like `mov x2, #10` it has to convert that `10` to a `1010`. I think it does so via a lookup table or hardware somehow.
I am curious, I've always given computers hex values as I feel like it would be at least a few clock cycles to figure out what a base 10 representation of a number should be stored as.

Would it be possible it would be faster to use `%x`. As `%x` will give you the hexadecimal representation to work with. Then it will be much easier to convert the output to binary one digit at a time, make a lookup table for every 4 bits. But I'm guessing the persistent memory access will outweigh any gain.

```
fprintf(temporary.txt, "%x", 42)
```

From my armature eyes it seems like you took the right approach and tracked down the only bug. I'm just giving food for thought and thinking out loud a bit. For your purposes of learning the basics I think you did great. If you'd like to learn more about the metal and consider trying to find a way to implement my idea. If you do I'd love to hear about it.

Comment: I'm sorry your answer was deleted, I am not a moderator, but I believe that answers should be left to be up or down voted based on their merit, unless they are just completely off-topic or offensive. Having said that, your "gut feeling that there must be a way to use the computers converter. The computer clearly has one, probable hardwired" is incorrect. People code in decimal - yes, represented as a string no less - however this must be converted to binary, there is no shortcut to this. You would see this if you looked at the output of a compiler.

Comment: I also, just wanted to say there is merit to looking and thinking 'outside the box' as you have suggested, otherwise we become stagnant, yours is the way to innovation.

Comment: Thank you for your kind and informative reply's. I am shocked to find there is no shortcut. I need to learn how to compile to assembly (probably just a gcc optional argument), as it will help me learn a-lot. Also it seems (based on your replies) my using hex inputs is more efficient than decimal, right?

Comment: "my using hex inputs is more efficient than decimal, right?" No, you have to remember that when you are typing in source code, you are not typing "hex" or "decimal" numbers, you are typing in "string" representations of them. So when your program is compiled, these strings must be parsed and converted to the actual binary representations of the numbers. Ex. If you type decimal "31" it is ascii chars 51 and 49, if you type hex "1F" it is ascii chars 49 and 70, both must be converted to binary 00011111 possibly with many more leading zeros depending on the size of int you are using.

Comment: Interesting, I was coming g back to edit my reply, as obviously I know what the assembly code looks like, to ask what you mean by examining the source code. (It sounds like a fun yet daunting exercise to try to map assembly commands to their respective numerical representation, probably after converting to hex) .................................................................  Now-I-am-again-surprised by your reply. It seems to imply anytime we use a number in our code it must use several clock cycles of a core. There must be a way to avoid this, to fill the address with the appropriate binary

Comment: Hi Abstract Approach. I'm sorry your previous answer was deleted. I have edited your existing on to be inline with the rules and have added your old answer here. Whilst I think your answer could do with a bit more of a look over (sorry I'm stretched for time right now) I don't think your answer should be deleted.

Comment: @AbstractApproach - "It seems to imply anytime we use a number in our code it must use several clock cycles of a core." No, the conversion to binary is done at compile/assembly time. When your code is converted to machine language, which is what your executable is stored as, all numbers are binary. No conversions are necessary during execution.

Comment: Ah yes that makes sense. Sorry I did not consider the important difference between execution operations and compilation operations. As for the rest if the comments, and the edit. I haven't looked and don't plan too. I hope it still made people think "outside the box" as the kind spoken individual has put it above. Next time I dare to speak on here I will make sure to have a complete answer with examples. I'm sure you guys do what you do for a reason and I shouldn't let it bother me. I'm manic-depressive, which can be a super power sometimes, but leave me a fool others. I will try to abide norm

Comment: @AbstractApproach the gcc invocation to compile to assembly is 'gcc -S -Ofast x.c -o "-" -masm=intel' for compiling a file x.c. The part "-o -" means send output to the console - omit to write to a *.s file instead. The part "-masm=intel" tells gcc to use the more commonly seen intel assembler syntax.

Comment: @rivimey thanks, I looked at the man page for gcc a while back and figured this fact out (while using aarch64, same difference), but obviously I did not know it back when I wrote my version of the reply above. Thank you for taking the time to write it out.